# In Magento 2 how to add phtml block after newsletter in footer.?

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, newsletter-block

> I want to add html content after newsletter in footer section in luma
>   theme

Please suggest me how can i do that?

Comment: you have to provide us what you tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In luma, theme footer is picked by the default.xml file below is the path for the file

> /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

navigate to the above path open default.xml file
and add your phtml file below

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
```

below is the method to call phtml file in xml file

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\calssname" name="file_name" template="Magento_Theme::html/your_file.phtml" />
```

Comment: I know this well but my question is that is it possible to add block or any text after newsletter..?  Position of block or text would be after newsletter.